# How do I identify the Python version code was written for

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

how do I identify if Python code was written for 2.7 or 3.x automatically.

Thank you

Comment: It's determined by you environment variables instead of Python script. For example `python --version` to check default Python version.

Comment: look for things that are incompatible between the two versions. print statements, future imports, or something along those lines.

Comment: Don't think you can

Comment: [@pinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070310/pinas), can you provide a sample of what you want to check? That may help us.

Comment: You can't tell a script is to be interpreted by Python 2.7 or Python 3 if I just give you `print('hello world')`. It can be interpreted by both versions.

Comment: Go through the `six` library. Everthing provided there is a difference you can check for.

Comment: @PrinceOfCreation I am more looking for a generic answer. I frequently have to review code snippets of various size and I'd like to have a possibility to identify if the python version it is meant for :)

Comment: I guess you could try running the stuff under both versions and seeing which one works

Comment: @pinas then you should google "difference between Python2 and 3". Also read PEP if you can. For example some new keywords are added to Python 3 like `await` and `async`

Answer (score 1):

You could develop an algorithm that searches for `print()` functions, f-strings, and other python3-exclusive features